# Can't upload BLOB with SAS Token

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

I have a Xamarin UWP app built using Azure Mobile Apps and I am trying to upload a BLOB to Azure storage with a SAS token and the .Net Azure Storage client (8.4.0).  I am able to generate the SAS token for my container via an Easy API Node function but when I try to use it to upload the file, I get an error "*Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.*"

**Easy API Code: for GetUploadToken**

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');

function generateSasToken(container, blobName, permissions) {
    var connString = "<conn string from azure storage acct>"; // removed for StackOverflow question
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService(connString);

    var currentDate = new Date();
    var startDate = new Date(currentDate);
    startDate.setMinutes(currentDate.getMinutes() - 5);

    console.log("startDate:    " + startDate);

    console.log("current date: " + currentDate);

    var expiryDate = new Date(currentDate);
    expiryDate.setMinutes(currentDate.getMinutes() + 60);

    console.log("expiryDate:   " + expiryDate);    

    permissions = permissions || azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ;

    var sharedAccessPolicy = {
        AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: permissions,
            Start: startDate,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        }
    };

    var sasToken = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(container, blobName, sharedAccessPolicy);

    console.log("SAS Token: " + sasToken);
    return {
        token: sasToken,
        uri: blobService.getUrl(container, blobName, sasToken)
    };
}

module.exports = {
    "post": function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.body.Container) {
           console.log("Container: " + req.body.Container);
           console.log("BlobName:" + req.body.BlobName);
           console.log("Permissions:" + req.body.Permissions);

            // The following values can be used for permissions: 
            // "a" (Add), "r" (Read), "w" (Write), "d" (Delete), "l" (List)
            // Concatenate multiple permissions, such as "rwa" = Read, Write, Add
            var token = generateSasToken(req.body.Container, req.body.BlobName, req.body.Permissions);

            res.status(200).type('application/json').json(token);
        } else {
            res.status(400).type("text/plain").text("Specify a value for 'container");
        }
    }
};
```

**Easy API Output**

```
Container: sketches
BlobName:DSCF3726.JPG
Permissions:rwa
startDate:    Thu Oct 05 2017 14:39:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
current date: Thu Oct 05 2017 14:44:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
expiryDate:   Thu Oct 05 2017 15:44:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
SAS Token: st=2017-10-05T14%3A39%3A36Z&se=2017-10-05T15%3A44%3A36Z&sp=rwa&sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=...
```

**Upload Code**

```
internal async Task<string> UploadAsync(string fileName, byte[] dataArray)
{
    var sketchFile = new SketchFile
    {
        BlobName = fileName,
        Container = "sketches",
        Permissions = "rwa"
    };

    var response = await CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync<SketchFile, GetSasTokenResponse>(
        "GetUploadToken", 
        sketchFile);

    try
    {
        var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(response.Uri));

        await blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
    }
    catch (StorageException se)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error uploading {fileName}: {se.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage}.");

        return null;
    }

    var uri = response.Uri.Substring(0, response.Uri.IndexOf('?'));

    return uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I could reproduce this issue on my side. I assumed that it may caused by the `Permissions` you specified. As [Permissions for a blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Constructing-a-Service-SAS?redirectedfrom=MSDN#specifying-permissions) states about the `Add` permission as follows:

> Allowed operations: Add a block to an append blob.

You could use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer) and generate the sas token for your block blob to narrow this issue.

Per my test, change the **Permissions** to `rw`, then I could successfully upload my file to azure blob storage.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks!